# Float image list item left and other list items right

Tags: html, css, list

I have an unordered list consisting of a list item with an image inside and some other list items with just text inside.
I'd like to float the list item with the image to the left, while the rest of the list items should be floated to the right.

What is the best way to do this?
(Also, is it bad style to have an image inside a list item?)

Comment: Please post your [mcve] showing what you've tried. And no, there's nothing wrong with having an image in a list item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having an image inside of the list item is fine. However, there is no pure CSS way to recognize that the list item contains an image and style it differently.

What you could do is add a class to the list item, and then style using that.

```css
ul {
border: 1px solid red;
padding: 0;
max-width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
}

li {
list-style-type: none;
float: right;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 1px solid green;
}

li.image {
float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>

<li class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
<li>Text</li>
<li>Text</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked :)
And thanks for the elaborate code, that's very helpful.